# django deleting models and overriding delete method

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models

```
class Vhost(models.Model):
    dns = models.ForeignKey(DNS)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    extra = models.TextField()


class ApplicationInstalled(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    app = models.ForeignKey(Application)
    ver = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationVersion)
    vhost = models.ForeignKey(Vhost)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="/")


    def delete(self):

        #
        # remove the files
        #
        print "need to remove some files"


        super(ApplicationInstalled, self).delete()
```

If I do the following

```
>>> vhost = Vhost.objects.get(id=10)
>>> vhost.id
10L
>>> ApplicationInstalled.objects.filter(vhost=vhost)
[<ApplicationInstalled: http://wiki.jy.com/>]
>>> vhost.delete()
>>> ApplicationInstalled.objects.filter(vhost=vhost)
[]
```

As you can see there is an applicationinstalled object linked to vhost but when I delete the vhost, the applicationinstalled object is gone but the print never gets called.

Any easy way to do this without iterating through the objects in the vhost delete?

**Solution**

```
def delete_apps(sender, **kwargs):
    obj = kwargs['instance']

    print "need to delete apps"


pre_delete.connect(delete_apps, sender=ApplicationInstalled)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ever since django got [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/signals/) I've found that I almost never need to override save/delete.

Whatever you need to do can likely be accomplished in a [pre_delete](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete) or [post_delete](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete) signal.

In this case, it seems that you'd want is to [delete in bulk](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete) in a pre_delte signal.